# Error trying to implement facebook sdk on android using unity(logcat):

Tags: android, facebook-unity-sdk

I am getting this error in logcat when trying to login into facebook, via android app.

I can see whats wrong.

```
10-28 22:33:57.950: E/ActivityThread(28413): Service
```

> com.facebook.katana.platform.PlatformService has leaked
>   ServiceConnection
>   com.facebook.fbservice.ops.DefaultBlueServiceOperationFactory$DefaultOperation$BlueServiceConnection@4307e1d8
>   that was originally bound here 10-28 22:33:57.950:
>   E/ActivityThread(28413): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service
>   com.facebook.katana.platform.PlatformService has leaked
>   ServiceConnection
>   com.facebook.fbservice.ops.DefaultBlueServiceOperationFactory$DefaultOperation$BlueServiceConnection@4307e1d8
>   that was originally bound here 10-28 22:33:57.950:
>   E/ActivityThread(28413):  at
>   android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.(LoadedApk.java:965)
>   10-28 22:33:57.950: E/ActivityThread(28413):  at
>   android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:859) 10-28
>   22:33:57.950: E/ActivityThread(28413):    at
>   android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1270) 10-28
>   22:33:57.950: E/ActivityThread(28413):    at
>   android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1262) 10-28
>   22:33:57.950: E/ActivityThread(28413):    at
>   android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:394)
>   10-28 22:33:57.950: E/ActivityThread(28413):  at
>   com.facebook.fbservice.ops.DefaultBlueServiceOperationFactory$DefaultOperation.i(DefaultBlueServiceOperationFactory.java:461)
>   10-28 22:33:57.950: E/ActivityThread(28413):  at
>   com.facebook.fbservice.ops.DefaultBlueServiceOperationFactory$DefaultOperation.a(DefaultBlueServiceOperationFactory.java:419)
>   10-28 22:33:57.950: E/ActivityThread(28413):  at
>   com.facebook.katana.platform.PlatformService.a(PlatformService.java:184)
>   10-28 22:33:57.950: E/ActivityThread(28413):  at
>   com.facebook.katana.platform.PlatformService.a(PlatformService.java:36)
>   10-28 22:33:57.950: E/ActivityThread(28413):  at
>   com.facebook.katana.platform.PlatformService$MessageHandler.handleMessage(PlatformService.java:71)
>   10-28 22:33:57.950: E/ActivityThread(28413):  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 10-28
>   22:33:57.950: E/ActivityThread(28413):    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 10-28 22:33:57.950:
>   E/ActivityThread(28413):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4904) 10-28
>   22:33:57.950: E/ActivityThread(28413):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 10-28
>   22:33:57.950: E/ActivityThread(28413):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 10-28 22:33:57.950:
>   E/ActivityThread(28413):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
>   10-28 22:33:57.950: E/ActivityThread(28413):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557) 10-28
>   22:33:57.950: E/ActivityThread(28413):    at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 10-28 22:33:58.060:
>   E/Trace(12883): error opening trace file: No such file or directory
>   (2) 10-28 22:33:58.991: E/XTWiFi(468): [MessageQ] ProcessNewMessage:
>   [XTWiFi-CS] unknown deliver target [OS-Agent] 10-28 22:34:00.903:
>   E/WifiStateMachine(726): Fetch RSSI NEW RSSI = -46 10-28 22:34:00.983:
>   E/XTWiFi(468): [MessageQ] ProcessNewMessage: [XTWiFi-PE] unknown
>   deliver target [OS-Agent] 10-28 22:34:03.917: E/WifiStateMachine(726):
>   Fetch RSSI NEW RSSI = -44 10-28 22:34:03.987: E/XTWiFi(468):
>   [MessageQ] ProcessNewMessage: [XTWiFi-CS] unknown deliver target
>   [OS-Agent] 10-28 22:34:06.930: E/WifiStateMachine(726): Fetch RSSI NEW
>   RSSI = -46 10-28 22:34:08.992: E/XTWiFi(468): [MessageQ]
>   ProcessNewMessage: [XTWiFi-CS] unknown deliver target [OS-Agent] 10-28
>   22:34:09.943: E/WifiStateMachine(726): Fetch RSSI NEW RSSI = -46 10-28
>   22:34:12.956: E/WifiStateMachine(726): Fetch RSSI NEW RSSI = -46 10-28
>   22:34:13.987: E/XTWiFi(468): [MessageQ] ProcessNewMessage: [XTWiFi-CS]
>   unknown deliver target [OS-Agent] 10-28 22:34:15.979:
>   E/WifiStateMachine(726): Fetch RSSI NEW RSSI = -46 10-28 22:34:18.993:
>   E/WifiStateMachine(726): Fetch RSSI NEW RSSI = -46 10-28 22:34:18.993:
>   E/XTWiFi(468): [MessageQ] ProcessNewMessage: [XTWiFi-CS] unknown
>   deliver target [OS-Agent] 10-28 22:34:21.996: E/WifiStateMachine(726):
>   Fetch RSSI NEW RSSI = -42 10-28 22:34:23.417: E/ActivityThread(28413):
>   Service com.facebook.katana.platform.PlatformService has leaked
>   ServiceConnection
>   com.facebook.fbservice.ops.DefaultBlueServiceOperationFactory$DefaultOperation$BlueServiceConnection@432251f8
>   that was originally bound here 10-28 22:34:23.417:
>   E/ActivityThread(28413): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service
>   com.facebook.katana.platform.PlatformService has leaked
>   ServiceConnection
>   com.facebook.fbservice.ops.DefaultBlueServiceOperationFactory$DefaultOperation$BlueServiceConnection@432251f8
>   that was originally bound here 10-28 22:34:23.417:
>   E/ActivityThread(28413):  at
>   android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.(LoadedApk.java:965)
>   10-28 22:34:23.417: E/ActivityThread(28413):  at
>   android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:859) 10-28
>   22:34:23.417: E/ActivityThread(28413):    at
>   android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1270) 10-28
>   22:34:23.417: E/ActivityThread(28413):    at
>   android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1262) 10-28
>   22:34:23.417: E/ActivityThread(28413):    at
>   android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:394)
>   10-28 22:34:23.417: E/ActivityThread(28413):  at
>   com.facebook.fbservice.ops.DefaultBlueServiceOperationFactory$DefaultOperation.i(DefaultBlueServiceOperationFactory.java:461)
>   10-28 22:34:23.417: E/ActivityThread(28413):  at
>   com.facebook.fbservice.ops.DefaultBlueServiceOperationFactory$DefaultOperation.a(DefaultBlueServiceOperationFactory.java:419)
>   10-28 22:34:23.417: E/ActivityThread(28413):  at
>   com.facebook.katana.platform.PlatformService.a(PlatformService.java:184)
>   10-28 22:34:23.417: E/ActivityThread(28413):  at
>   com.facebook.katana.platform.PlatformService.a(PlatformService.java:36)
>   10-28 22:34:23.417: E/ActivityThread(28413):  at
>   com.facebook.katana.platform.PlatformService$MessageHandler.handleMessage(PlatformService.java:71)
>   10-28 22:34:23.417: E/ActivityThread(28413):  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 10-28
>   22:34:23.417: E/ActivityThread(28413):    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 10-28 22:34:23.417:
>   E/ActivityThread(28413):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4904) 10-28
>   22:34:23.417: E/ActivityThread(28413):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 10-28
>   22:34:23.417: E/ActivityThread(28413):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 10-28 22:34:23.417:
>   E/ActivityThread(28413):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
>   10-28 22:34:23.417: E/ActivityThread(28413):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557) 10-28
>   22:34:23.417: E/ActivityThread(28413):    at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 10-28 22:34:23.477:
>   E/Trace(12961): error opening trace file: No such file or directory
>   (2)

This too....

```
    10-29 18:36:05.110: E/AndroidRuntime(8367): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-29 18:36:05.110: E/AndroidRuntime(8367): java.lang.Error: FATAL EXCEPTION [main]
10-29 18:36:05.110: E/AndroidRuntime(8367): Unity version     : 4.2.1f4
10-29 18:36:05.110: E/AndroidRuntime(8367): Device model      : LGE VS930 4G
10-29 18:36:05.110: E/AndroidRuntime(8367): Device fingerprint: verizon_lge/d1lv_VZW_US/d1lv:4.1.2/JZO54K/VS93022A.1376984517:user/release-keys
10-29 18:36:05.110: E/AndroidRuntime(8367): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.motorcity3d.splitting8s/com.facebook.unity.FBUnityPlayerActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=64206, result=0, data=null} to activity {com.motorcity3d.splitting8s/com.facebook.unity.FBUnityPlayerActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-29 18:36:05.110: E/AndroidRuntime(8367):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2596)
10-29 18:36:05.110: E/AndroidRuntime(8367):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2624)
10-29 18:36:05.110: E/AndroidRuntime(8367):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
10-29 18:36:05.110: E/AndroidRuntime(8367):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:137)
10-29 18:36:05.110: E/AndroidRuntime(8367):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1203)
10-29 18:36:05.110: E/AndroidRuntime(8367):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-29 18:36:05.110: E/AndroidRuntime(8367):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-29 18:36:05.110: E/AndroidRuntime(8367):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4904)
10-29 18:36:05.110: E/AndroidRuntime(8367):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-29 18:36:05.110: E/AndroidRuntime(8367):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-29 18:36:05.110: E/AndroidRuntime(8367):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
10-29 18:36:05.110: E/AndroidRuntime(8367):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
10-29 18:36:05.110: E/AndroidRuntime(8367):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-29 18:36:05.110: E/AndroidRuntime(8367): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=64206, result=0, data=null} to activity {com.blah.bleh/com.facebook.unity.FBUnityPlayerActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-29 18:36:05.110: E/AndroidRuntime(8367):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3193)
10-29 18:36:05.110: E/AndroidRuntime(8367):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2583)
10-29 18:36:05.110: E/AndroidRuntime(8367):     ... 12 more
10-29 18:36:05.110: E/AndroidRuntime(8367): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-29 18:36:05.110: E/AndroidRuntime(8367):     at com.facebook.unity.FBUnityPlayerActivity.onActivityResult(FBUnityPlayerActivity.java:15)
10-29 18:36:05.110: E/AndroidRuntime(8367):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5432)
10-29 18:36:05.110: E/AndroidRuntime(8367):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3189)
10-29 18:36:05.110: E/AndroidRuntime(8367):     ... 13 more
```

Comment: This same thing is driving me CRAZY.

Comment: Thank God it isn't just me.

Comment: It just started working out of the blue....:|

Comment: If anyone needs help getting this to work let me know and I will help you walk through it.  It should be clearer on the FB site and unity site on how to implement this.

Comment: Jason: can you put an answer here?

Comment: Aaron,  Why is this working on my phone but any others...I've only tried nexus and galaxy S3 so far.  Is there some manifest permission I am missing?  Am I suppose to have the login disabled on the FB dev settings page?

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer here; d'you think you could pare down your listings a bit though? This is rather cumbersome to read...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this issue by only using "publish_actions" in the login call.  Works on Galaxy S3 now.